# EXCEL - Comparing a date to a column of date ranges and then, if within the range, comparing to a row cell

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I am having trouble getting a working formula for this without using VBA (I can use VBA if needed but have no experience with it). So what I am attempting to do is take a given date, see if it is within a list if date ranges, and if it is within a certain date range, it should compare to a cell within the same row that it matches to the date range. If it doesn't, it should continue to search until it finds another date range match or exhausts the list and returns a value of false.

So far I have tried something along the lines of `If(NumbertoMatch(VLOOKUP(AND(Date>Date1,Date<Date2),Table,NumbertoMatch,False),TRUE,FALSE)`

Edit #2 Adding an image of what the cells would compare to.

[image]

Edit #3 Adding a rule that the formula should account for.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLyhY.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `=INDEX(C2:C6,SUMPRODUCT(--(date()>A2:A6),--(date<B2:B6),ROW(C2:C6)-1))` with date set to something will return the value from C where date matches a date range.

Comment: `=INDEX(C2:C6,MATCH(1,(date>A2:A6)*(date<B2:B6),0),1)` is an array formula that does the same thing

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your data layout with a few rows of sample data and mock up the desired result manually? It's hard to picture what you want to achieve if all we have is a formula that doesn't work. Edit your question to add a screenshot and explanation. Don't do that in a comment. Then post a comment and mention @teylyn to notify your change.

Comment: @teylyn Done.

So, I think I should also note that it is Excel 2016 Mac and that the last row is what I ultimately want but would be happy settling from the TRUE/FALSE second to last row as well.

The formula would take either cell G2 or H2 and then compare it against ALL of the other dates and cells for a match. Cells G2 and H2 are linked, just as cells A2 and B2 are

Comment: @teylyn Also added a photo of what would be compared. So the order in which it compares doesn't really matter, as long as it is the identifiers and dates are linked to each other. Also, the formula needs to be created so that I can easily apply the rule to hundreds of date/identifiers.

Comment: I don't understand the latest screenshot. Why would I6 be #N/A and I7 be 16 when the data is exactly the same?

Comment: 2 questions. what is column b for?  why does edit # 3 image not have the true/false output column?  the date range and identifier comparisons can be done in vba very easily.

Comment: Column B is what the date range (columns C and D) are from (3 months prior to one week prior from column B). The True/False column is not needed now that I know there is a solution to just output the row number. Teylyn's formula below works but I have had issues with it breaking if things are not in a particular order (for example the dates must be sorted in a particular order (newest to oldest. In summary, the goal is to have a cell in column G find a date range match between columns C and D AND the corresponding linked identifier next to it in columns H match column A

Comment: @AshtonMorgan Another issue with the formula vs VBA is that subsequent matches are ignored. If a row number is matched, further values that may also match are ignored.

Comment: First, I am new at this as you may have been able to ascertain from the 8 reputation I am at. I thought you could check both as answers that work and both would have check marks (First question I ever asked on this site). Your solution is great, and I made sure to let you know that it was. I have checked your answer back but I still want Ashton to know that his solution is working as well for me. Thank you for all the time you both put into helping me. I am very grateful and have started answering questions on other stack exchange sites where I can contribute (so I am not just a leech).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this screenshot:

[image]

The formula in J2 is

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((G2>=$C$2:$C$15)*(G2<=$D$2:$D$15)),MATCH(1,(G2>=$C$2:$C$15)*(G2<=$D$2:$D$15),0)+1,"")
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

The formula in I2 uses that row number and compares the identifier in that row with the value in H2. If there is no match, that comparison will throw an error, so the IfError catches that and turns it into a FALSE.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,J2)=H2,FALSE)
```

Do not use whole columns in the array formula, as that will slow things down.

With formulas you will only ever find the FIRST occurrence of a match, so returning several row numbers for multiple matches will not be possible.

Edit: Explanation of the MATCH function.

```
MATCH(1,(G2>=$C$2:$C$15)*(G2<=$D$2:$D$15),0)
```

When entered as an array function, the following will happen:

- `(G2>=$C$2:$C$15)` will resolve to an array of True or False values, one for each cell
- `(G2<=$D$2:$D$15)` will resolve to an array of True or False values, one for each row
- these two arrays are multiplied one row at a time. If a TRUE is multiplied with a TRUE, the result is a 1. All other combinations will be 0.
- That is the range that will be inspected for a matching 1. The position of the first 1 will be returned

[image]

Since the data starts in row 2 and I want the absolute row number, I have to add a 1 to the result from Match. Match returns a 12 because the date is matched to the 12th row of the data, which is row 13 in the spreadsheet.

You can see these steps play out with the Evaluate Formula tool on the Formulas ribbon.

Another edit:

This formula will only return TRUE if the date in column G falls in the time range AND the identifier in column H is the same as in column A:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,IF(SUMPRODUCT((G2>=$C$2:$C$15)*(G2<=$D$2:$D$15)),MATCH(1,(G2>=$C$2:$C$15)*(G2<=$D$2:$D$15)*(H2=$A$2:$A$15),0)+1,""))=H2,FALSE)
```

Again, confirm with Ctrl + Shift + Enter. Also if there are multiple matches, only the first match will trigger the TRUE.

Or if you want just the row number

```
=MATCH(1,(G2>=$C$2:$C$16)*(G2<=$D$2:$D$16)*(H2=$A$2:$A$16),0)+1
```

Comment: Nice answer! I think that H2 is provided, and we are meant to look up if the Collection Date has the provided Identifier or not.

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit Oh, I see. I totally misread that. I have changed my answer.

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit is correct. The two columns that would require formulas are I and J, as the Identifier in column A is linked to the dates in B and C, while the Identifier in H is linked to the date in column G. The entire goal is see if the matched pair in G/H falls within the date range with the same identifier in A/C/D

Comment: @teylyn You are awesome! The only thing I need help with now is deciphering how you handled the match function. I don't have my information in the same columns and although it is correctly matching the dates, it is returning the first row which matches the date range without checking to see if the Identifiers match (Column A matches column H). I think this issue may be due to me not understanding alter the match portion

Comment: I added an explanation for the Match function. Let me know if that solves your issue or if you need more help.

Comment: @teylyn Ok, so I think we are almost there but not quite yet. Is there any way to combine them into one function so that it only outputs the row number if identifier matches, falls within the date range of the matching identifier, and just continues checking if it doesn't until it finds one that does? That's part of the reason I thought nesting an argument inside a VLOOKUP function may have worked. The way it works now, as you get further down the list, it will match to a date range early in the rows, even if the identifier doesn't match.

Comment: Also, I can rearrange columns if needed to be able to use functions like INDIRECT as a conditional. Finally, while I have never used VBA, I can follow everything you have done so far, so if you think it is something I can do in VBA better, maybe that route would be better?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "the way it works now". My formula will find the first row where the date in cell G2 falls between the dates in columns C and D. Yes, the formula can be combined into one. Just put the formula from J2 in the position where the formula in I2 references J2. If there are several date ranges that the G2 date falls into, then only the first one will be returned. The formula will stop looking after the first match.

Comment: The whole data set is a very unfortunate affair and very hard to work with using lookup formulas. Vlookup will not make a difference. The Index/Match combination is much more powerful than Vlookup.

Comment: @teylyn What I mean is that even if the date falls into the first matching date range, it should continue to search if associated Identifier doesn't match.

Comment: I will try to make an example

Comment: Ok, I see. I thought of a possible workaround. Is it possible to easily separate the data onto multiple sheets? For example, from the above example, it would be easy to use the formula you created if I could make all the identifier A data and their associated dates move to a sheet labeled A and B move to another sheet. That way, the formula created would only be applied to the date ranges per sheet which have already been separated, preventing it from just matching the first date range it comes across, even if it is not the correct matched identifier.

Comment: I added another formula that takes into account the identifier and will only return a match if the identifier matches too

Answer (score 0):

VBA solution assumes the data is in worksheet 1 with columns A, B, C, D, G & H populated.  The code will grab the matching row # to column I.  Copy this code to a module.  If there is more than one row then it separates them with comma's as seen in this screenshot

[image: screenshot]

use this code

```
Sub FindRow()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim collDateRng As Range: Set collDateRng = ws.Range("G2", ws.Range("G2").End(xlDown))
Dim rng As Range
Dim resultsRng As Range
Dim rowRng As Range
Dim result As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ws
    collDateRng.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
    For Each rng In collDateRng
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="<" & rng.Value
            .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=">" & rng.Value
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 4).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    .Select
                    Set resultsRng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                Else
                    GoTo NothingFound
                End If
            End With
        End With

        For Each rowRng In resultsRng.Rows
            If result <> "" Then
                result = result & ", " & rowRng.Row
            Else
                result = rowRng.Row
            End If
        Next rowRng
        rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = result
        result = ""

NothingFound:
    Next rng

    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Cells(1, 1).Select
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```