# Matching a row number and value to a row on another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

As the title suggests, I am trying to create a system where a cell (which matches to a specific row) will search another sheet, find a number which matches its row number, and then puts in the paired value. I have attached a screenshot for a clearer picture.

This is what I have tried so far without any success.

`IF(INDEX(A2:B8,2,2)=?,____,"")`

I sort of understand the INDEX and MATCH function independently, but have no concrete understanding of how to incorporate the two for this problem. Also, I have already attempted to search google for help on this but have had difficulty even knowing what to enter as search terms, so help on that would be great as well for future problems.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? `Vlookup()`/`Index/Match`?

Comment: @BruceWayne Edited to include what I have tried

Comment: Can you include the actual formula used? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using VBA you can accomplish this.  just paste this code into a new module and run it.

```
Sub PasteToNewSheet()
Dim wsSource As Worksheet: Set wsSource = Worksheets(1)
Dim lastrow As Long: lastrow = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim wsDest As Worksheet: Set wsDest = Worksheets.Add(After:=wsSource)
Dim rngRows As Range: Set rngRows = wsSource.Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
Dim rng As Range
wsDest.Range("A1").Value = "Value"

For Each rng In rngRows
    If rng = "" then
        rng = rng
    ElseIf wsDest.Cells(rng.Value, 1) = "" Then
        wsDest.Cells(rng.Value, 1) = rng.Offset(, 1).Value
    ElseIf wsDest.Cells(rng.Value, 2) = "" Then
        wsDest.Cells(rng.Value, 2) = rng.Offset(, 1).Value
    ElseIf wsDest.Cells(rng.Value, 3) = "" Then
        wsDest.Cells(rng.Value, 3) = rng.Offset(, 1).Value
    End If
Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. After running, I received the error "Runtime error 1004" Application defined or object-defined error

Comment: i made it so you would run it while you have sheet1 active, and the code had to be in a module not in sheet code.  i updated it so that it will work from anywhere just make sure the first sheet is the one with the row numbers and values.

Comment: I think I figured out what is going wrong. The data I am working with has blanks for some of the row numbers. When I removed the "Row Number" 3, it gave me that error. Maybe I can just replace all of the blank cells in the row number column with 9999 and then if will just ignore the blanks?

Comment: if that cell is blank it will give you the error, because it uses that number to find the row number on sheet 2.  i changed to the code to basically skip those so it should work now without you having to do anything.  if you ever want to change it you can change from rng = rng to rng = 9999 or any other value you want if you want it to stand out.  you can even make it change the color of the blank cells.  let me know what you want to do, but the code is edited now and should work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ashton. I really appreciate it.

Comment: The code you put together for this problem is beautiful. I have another question on SE (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939594/excel-comparing-a-date-to-a-column-of-date-ranges-and-then-if-within-the-rang) that continues to break and doesn't do exactly what I want it to do. If you have any time, maybe you could help me with a VBA for it as well?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following in A2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$8,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$B$8=ROW(),ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$8),999999),COLUMN(A1))-1),"")
```

Array formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>
Drag the formula in the same row and down.

Sheet1!$A$2:$A$8, Sheet1!$B$2:$B$8 are Row and Value column
If() will test each value in A2:A8 for the Row() in the new sheet and return the Row number in sheet1
99999 to have a maximum value if no Row() match (false part of the If)
Column(A1) to return small( ,1)
It will become Column(B1) when you drag in the same row (for multiple value of same Row Number)
Iferror will return "" empty if no number

Sheet1

```
    A    B
    Row Value
    5   20
    2   30
    7   40
    8   50
    2   60
    3   70
    2   100
```

Sheet2 result

```
Row/Col   A     B    C 
 1    
 2        30    60  100
 3        70        
 4          
 5        20        
 6          
 7        40        
 8        50
```

Comment: thanks to your post, I learned kbd tag today. May I selfishly ask where I may find the style cheatsheet?

Comment: @Ryan L You can write your Data in Excel, copy - paste in answer, select and press Ctrl+K it will help

Comment: @yass Thank you for your answer. For some reason, I am not able to translate this simple example to the workbook I am using. When change all of the cells to match the ones used in the example, the entire thing is blank even though I know where specific matches should be.

Comment: after modifying the formula press Ctrl+Shift+Enter at the same time array formula

Comment: and keep $ for fixed references can you paste your formula in comment?

Comment: @yass `{=IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet1'!$F$2:$F$430,SMALL(IF('Sheet1'!$E$2:$F$430=ROW(),ROW('Sheet1'!E$2:$E$431),999999),COLUMN(A1))-1),"")}`

Comment: ROW('Sh‌​eet1'!E$2:$E$431) should be OW('Sh‌​eet1'!E$2:$E$430) and no need for 'sheet1' just Sheet1 if no blank space in the name and after small  'Sheet1'!$E$2:‌​$F$430=ROW() should be 'Sheet1'!$E$2:‌​$E$430=ROW() just column E you cannot use 2 columns

Comment: The formula become {=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$F$2:$F$430,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$E$2:‌​$E$430=ROW(),ROW(Sh‌​eet1!E$2:$E$430),99‌​9999),COLUMN(A1))-1)‌​,"")}

Comment: and do not write {} just press Ctrl+Shift+Enter after you copy the formula and paste it edit it and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter and drag it down